# How to find out if my car AC needs extra oil and how much to top up?

Tags: oil, ac, car, leak

My car AC has been dead for a couple of years now and I was wondering the following things:

- How could that affect the AC oil level?
- Is there anything I should be worried about considering my AC system has been idle for a few years
- How can I figure out if there is any oil missing?
- How can I figure out how much extra oil to add if any is needed?

Comment: No way to check the amount. Unless you had a leak and leaked the oil out while running it still has the proper amount of oil.

Comment: Awesome @Moab, so I should be ok then. Is there any point doing such a test to at least making sure there is oil in there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uI5x7VPpvVY

Comment: Oil circulates though the entire system, so no way to measure it. There might be a way to indicate there is oil present but will not indicate how much is in the system. When in doubt add 2 ounces.

Comment: Maybe pertinent is the age of the car. I had an old BMW735iSE where the aircon would only run when the button was pressed. All well and good, I thought, who needs aircon in winter. Little did I know that letting it sit idle for 6 months would mean the seals ripped themselves to shreds next time I used it. My brother in law, an aircon service engineer, pointed out my dumb mistake. My current much newer Merc doesn’t let this pump idle, it spins it up itself to prevent this damage.

Answer (score 0):

Checking oil as described in the video can only be done when the a/c system remains sealed and can maintain vacuum. [Your other question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/76814/can-you-visually-detect-an-ac-car-leak) presumably about the same vehicle indicates the a/c system does leak.

A leaky a/c system loses vacuum and becomes inoperable. Because the system is now empty (two years is a long time), you cannot assess its oil level using the method demonstrated in the video.

Comment: Also if the vehicle has been sitting s long period of time without a charge, air and moisture has been introduced and moisture will damage A.C. components. The accumulator\drier would have to be replaced the pump may have some internal corrosion. It should have all necessary parts replaced, the system flushed. After the system is flushed a professional will know how much oil to install. Each component requires a specified amount of oil.

Comment: David, yes that is the same vehicle. I am aware the system must be leaking, but I am not sure what it means in term of oil level and how to top it up.

Comment: @Jupiter, it sounds like the entire system is good to replace. Are you saying I should anyway, no matter what, flush the oil from the system as some of it will be missing (and while I'm at it, check all the AC components)? Also, should vacuuming the system not be good enough to remove all the moisture from the system? Why would the accumulator need replacement? Thanks

Comment: An accumalator driers purpose is to remove any moisture in the system. If it is exposed to air (which it will be in an uncharged system) it will be exposed to the moisture in the air. This same moisture can contaminate every other component causing corrosion. If you want risk free AC, everything should be flushed to start with a clean system. At the point you are at now it would be best for the pros. Proceed on your own if you like, but my rule to myself is: if I work on my A.C. without the right equipment, don't cry to myself when it don't work.

Comment: Vacuuming will remove all the moisture but cannot repair the accumalator drier and cannot repair the damage that the moisture created.

Comment: @Jupiter, I will replace the accumulator as you suggested. What type of equipment are you referring to when saying I need the right one? Something to check the corrosion? I want to do it properly. Please let me know what approach you would take. Many thanks

Comment: Oh, I see, I saw you other comment in my other tread, where you said I need to check for leaks with the system loaded. So I need a recovery tank, I see, fair enough! How would you check for corrosion or any other potential dirts and problems?

Comment: @toughQuestions To evacuate an a/c/ system properly and legally, you need all sorts of specialized tools including - depending on your location - a license to work with, handle,  and store refrigerant. This is a serious and unique endeavour, and should be handed to a professional to accomplish.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, how about using a leak sealer/stopper? Do they work? Any cons?

Comment: I have no experience with them. Assuming you can fix the leak(s) - and that's a very big assumption for a novice working on an old system - do all the various electromechanical sensors work right? Are the receiver, dryer, condensor, and compressor in good operating condition? Then you must pull a vacuum (using a good vacuum pump and a/c gauges) that holds over time, then obtain and add the right amount of the right type of refrigerant. Did your leak repair interfere with the oil in the system? There are a lot of parts and steps. For me, this is work for an expert with knowledge, not for me.

Comment: Understood @DavidSupportsMonica. FIW, I trust myself far more than any random mechanics out there. I have been fixing my cars since 2003 as a hobyist and each time I let a "pro" do a job I had no time to do or could not be bother doing, they simply made a mess or they tried (and often succeeded) in ripping me off. I am talking about many situations here. I am sure there are plenty of great mechanics out there, but I was never lucky enough to find one of them unfortunately.

Comment: Fair enough. I think the specialized knowledge and tools to accomplish a/c work means it's something I won't try. BTW, I'm 72 and have been wrenching on bikes and cars (and homes) since the mid-60s. But I accept that YMMV. Good luck with it.